# fibonacci and non-fibonacci coding

Tags: python, fibonacci

I apologize since this might be a common question, but I think I am looking for a quite specific answer that wouldn't be found in other topics. Basically, I am quite confused about the flow of adding numbers. Here are two similar codes that compute numbers differently. Is there any simple explanation for this?

```
>>> a = 0
>>> b = 1
>>> while b <1000:
    print b
        a, b = b, a+b


1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377,610,987

>>> a =0
>>> b=1
>>> while b<1000:
       print b
       a = b
       b = a+b


1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512
```

Comment: I tagged this as "python" for you. Don't forget to specify what language and/or tools you're using so others can find your post easier and so it can be referenced in the future when someone is searching for an answer to the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference lies in what the values are WHEN swapped

`a, b = b, a+b`

sets a to b and sets a to a+b but the swaps are done relatively at the same time so it's not in order, ie the change in b doesn't respect that a was changed first.

In the second example

```
a = b

b = a+b
```

the values are changed and the 2nd statement respects the change of the first

Answer (score 1):

There is a precedence difference in the swap.
In the first example you are assigning:
a = 1
b = 1

In the second example you are assigning:
a = 1
b = 2

In order to achieve the same order of operations as the first example you'll have to use a temp var.

Comment: Actually, you're right. I didn't know that swapping was something that is built in. I thought that it simply assigns a to first and b to second when I typed a, b = 1,2.

Answer (score 0):

The assignments happen at the same time in the 1st code example, and serially in the 2nd, leading to a different answer.